# About Django for iPhone CSS

Tags: css

please help me, I could not change to iphone css from pc css

My pc.css and iphone.css is the same css

also I setting below:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width:320px) and (max-device-width:480px)" href="{% static "asset/js/iphone.css" %}"/>

</head>
</html>
```

`iphone.css` is:

```
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {

body{ 
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
    Max-width: 100%
}
}
```

Comment: There is django here? What do you exactly want?

Comment: No here django program, only html and css

Comment: i want for iphone that use the django web css